# Testing $A\mu + b = 0$ for a normal distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

Say $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^m$ are i.i.d observations from a multivariate normal distribution $N(\mu, \Sigma$).

How could I test the hypothesis $H_0:A \mu + b=0$ against $H_0:A \mu + b\neq0$, such that **A** is some invertible $2\times 2$ matrix and **b** is a 2D vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under $H_0$, the quadratic form
$$
(A\bar x+b)^T (A\Sigma A^T)^{-1}(A\bar x+b)
$$
is chi-square with 2 degrees of freedom.  If you substitute $\Sigma$ by its estimate $\hat\Sigma=\frac1{m-1} \sum_{i=1}^m (x_i-\bar x)(x_i-\bar x)^T $, then
$$
(A\bar x+b)^T (A\hat\Sigma A^T)^{-1}(A\bar x+b)
$$
is instead [Hotelling T-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution#Definition_2) distributed with $2$ and $m-1$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Can you explain why we are using the quadratic form to get inferences of $H_0$? We simply reject $H_0$ if $T>F$ right?

Comment: @CCZ23 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance